# Wrong number of arguments on Rack::Builder.new

Tags: ruby, rack

I apparently have a Rack::Builder misunderstanding. Inside my config.ru file i've got:

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/lobster'

class Shrimp
   SHRIMP_STRING = 'teste'

   def initialize(app)
      @app = app
   end

   def call(env)
     status, headers, response = @app.call(env)

     response_body = ""
     response.each { |part| response_body += part }
     response_body += "&lt;pre&gt;#{SHRIMP_STRING}&lt;/pre&gt;"

     headers["Content-Length"] = response_body.length.to_s

    [status, headers, response_body]
  end
end

app = Rack::Builder.new do
  use Rack::Lobster
  run Shrimp.new
end

Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run app
```

When I do a 
    rackup config.ru

I get a

```
/home/vagrant/config.ru:7:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
from /home/vagrant/config.ru:26:in `new'
```

Am I missing something? According to this [tutorial](http://rubylearning.com/blog/a-quick-introduction-to-rack/#C10) Rack::Builder.new only receives a block as a parameter.

EDIT: 
changing this line

```
run Shrimp.new
```

to:

```
run Shrimp
```

I still get a wrong number of arguments, but this time for Rack::Builder

```
ERROR ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:86:in `initialize'
```

Comment: Can you provide code of  `Shrimp` class also.

Comment: It's on the post @saurabh. It has two methods, initialize and call (as a Rack Middleware)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For Rack middleware, you don't need to do `Shrimp.new`, You just need to do `use Shrimp` and it should do.

You can find it's one example [here.](http://www.amberbit.com/blog/2011/07/13/introduction-to-rack-middleware/)

As par this link you only need to do following:

```
# config.ru
require 'rack'
require 'rack/lobster'
require 'shrimp'      

use Shrimp            
run Rack::Lobster.new
```

Comment: You are correct. But what arguments the Shrimp (as a Rack Middleware should receive?)

Comment: I edited my question, i keep getting the error, but this time with Rack::Builer.